# emacs public/protected/private label indentation of C++ header file not working for zero offset

Tags: c++, emacs, indentation

I cannot get zero offset for some things for my C++ header files in emacs even if I have it defined in my .emacs file.

The header file below shows a class definition inside two namespaces and most importantly the public keyword I would like to have with zero offset like below.

```
namespace n1
{
namespace n2 // no offset
{

class SomeClass // no offset from namespace open curly
{
public: // this line with zero offset
    SomeClass(); // offset 4
    ...
};

inline SomeClass::SomeClass() // no offset
{
}

} // n2
} // n2
```

In my .emacs file I have added label like this:

```
(c-set-offset 'label 0)
```

I used Ctrl-C Ctrl-S to find out what to modify. Other offsets I have defined in the .emacs file are working fine and also values other than 0 work for label.

When I set offset 0 for label it turns out to be 1 when hitting tab for that line. This is strange and looks like something else is overriding or adding a minimum of 1.

Can anyone explain how I can achieve what I want and maybe also an explanation what is happening currently?

Phew, this was my first question here. Thanks :)

UPDATE:

Thanks to the answers I have been able to get a bit farther, but still no solution overall, because changing the things necessary to get total offset 0 for the accessors result in other things I don't want. Thsi is where I'm currently:

```
(c-set-offset 'access-label 0)
```

I also needed to get the .h file to be understoor as C++, so I added:

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.h\\'" . c++-mode))
```

This alone is not removing the 1 offset I was seeing, but it seems there is also inclass for the accessor. Setting this to 0 actually results in total 0 offset.

```
(c-set-offset 'inclass 0)
```

Problem is that now other things such as members are with total of 0 like below:

```
class Foo
{
public:
Foo();
~Foo();
```

To remedy this I changed topmost-intro to offset 4

```
(c-set-offset 'topmost-intro 4)
```

Which in turn resulted in other changes for e.g. inline function declarations in the same file. All in all, I'm not sure how to tweak this the way I want it.

UPDATE2:

Added inline declaration of SomeClass ctor with no offset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you want access-label instead of label. See [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/ccmode/Syntactic-Symbols.html).

Comment: Same here, the access-label alone is not helping, but the link you provided gave me the necessary info what is adding 1.

Comment: Btw, You can leave the inclass offset and use a negative offset for access-label symbol.

Answer (score 2):

You want `access-label` instead of label, and if C-C C-S gave you `((label 1))` that's mean you are in C mode and not in C++ mode (C mode is the default for `.h` files).  If this is your problem, add

```
// Emacs, please set these
// Local Variables: ***
// mode: c++ ***
// End: ***
```

to the end of your .h file or

```
// -*- C++ -*-
```

at the start.

Comment: This is not completely giving the result I wanted, because access-label 0 will bechave the same as label 0. 1 offset coming from another one.

Comment: What's the value of innamespace offset?  (I wouldn't touch to inclass, and notes that negative offsets are possible as they are cumulative).

Comment: I was looking into that as well, but that messes up other things, becaue I want to have 0 offset for things inside namespaces. Maybe I just need to change the way I'd like it to look like? ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you use

```
(c-set-offset 'innamespace 0)
```

then the opening brace of a namespace does not increase the indentation level.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may want to use a negative number. For example, in my `c-offsets-alist`, I have:

```
(inclass . +)
```

Then in `.emacs`:

```
(c-set-offset 'access-label -1)
```

Which gets me my desired:

```
class A {
 public:
  A();
  ...
```