# emacs batch indent vs. cc-mode access-label

Tags: emacs, batch-file, cc-mode

I'm trying to batch indent source files using emacs.  I'm using the command:

```
$ emacs -batch Source.h -l emacs-format-file.el -f emacs-format-function
```

where emacs-format-file.el contains:

```
(defun emacs-format-function ()
 (c-set-style "gnu")
 (setq c-basic-offset 4)
 (c-set-offset 'access-label nil)
 (c-set-offset 'substatement-open 0)
 (indent-region (point-min) (point-max) nil)
 (untabify (point-min) (point-max))
 (save-buffer)
)
```

Emacs indents the file to my liking with one exception.  The "public", "private", and "protected" keywords are all indented an extra space:

```
 class Foo
 {
-public:
+ public:
```

I want to align these keywords with the preceding open bracket.  Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4490196/emacs-public-protected-private-label-indentation-of-c-header-file-not-working) I thought setting 'access-label' would fix this but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that emacs was processing the header file as C instead of C++.  The fix was to change the .el file to manually switch to C++ mode:

```
(defun c++-indent-region ()
  (c++-mode)
  (c-set-style "gnu")
  (setq c-basic-offset 4)
  (indent-region (point-min) (point-max) nil)
  (untabify (point-min) (point-max))
  (save-buffer)
)
```