# Getting emacs's access-label indentation to add an indentation level

Tags: c++, emacs, indentation

I was looking at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4490196/emacs-public-protected-private-label-indentation-of-c-header-file-not-working) and realized I had a similar concern that is not thoroughly answered there.

I want access specifiers to add a level of indentation. On [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/ccmode/Syntactic-Symbols.html) and [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/efaq/Customizing-C-and-C_002b_002b-indentation.html) page, I found that the syntactic symbol I need to indent is access-label. Thus, I need to use `(c-set-offset 'access-label '0)`.

However, this only indents the line containing the access label and not anything that comes after. What I get is this,

```
class foo {
  public:
  void someFunc(); // Doesn't take the indentation of the access label into account
  ...
  };
```

What I want is,

```
class foo {
  public:
    void someFunc();
  ...
  };
```

How would I do this? Is there some other variable I'm suppose to modify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use `inclass` to set the indenting of functions & members inside the class.
But this will lead to situation that functions & members in the `struct` will be indented by 2 tabs, instead of one, so we need to have a special function to set correct indentation width. I'm using [following config](https://github.com/alexott/emacs-configs/blob/master/rc/emacs-rc-ccmode.el#L32) to achieve this (I've got the snippet from somewhere in the internet, maybe from emacswiki)...

Comment: It's rather unfortunate that there isn't a more straightforward way to accomplish this. I'd imagine wanting to indent access labels would have come up more often.

Comment: for classes the config is straightforward, but for structs we need to make such tricks :-(

Answer (score 1):

If you use the braces on new line, the workaround above is not completely correct; you must check
if after first goto you are before an open brace. This is my more generale workaround:

```
(defun agb/c++-mode-hook ()
  (c-set-offset 'access-label '-)
  (c-set-offset 'topmost-intro '0)
  (c-set-offset 'inclass '(lambda (arg)
                            (let ((inclass (assoc 'inclass c-syntactic-context)))
                              (save-excursion
                                (goto-char (c-langelem-pos inclass))
                                (if (looking-at "{")
                                    (goto-char (c-langelem-pos (assoc 'class-open (c-guess-basic-syntax)))))
                                (if (or (looking-at "struct")
                                        (looking-at "typedef struct"))
                                    '+
                                  '++))))))
```